# Is it possible to retrieve brand colors without hardcoding

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

[image]

I am looking for a way to query the colors used by 'brand' classes in Salesforce, like here for example `slds-button_brand`. Currently I am hardcoding them, but someone has changed these colors so my custom elements don't look the same anymore. I want to refactor this stuff so I don't have to change my code everytime someone changes these. I searched for classes that would apply this and I wasn't successful. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the design tokens instead of hardcoding color values. Here are all the [design tokens](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/) for the colors in SLDS. You just need to convert these tokens to `camelCase` then while using in LWC.

Like `$brand-accessible` will become `var(--lwc-brandAccessible)`.

Example

```
.your-class{
     background-color: var(--lwc-brandAccessible);
}
```

You can also provide the fallback value for design tokens.

```
.your-class{
     background-color: var(--lwc-brandAccessible, <fallback value>);
}
```

More details on [How to use Design Tokens in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_design_tokens)